# How to select entry by date when date is a string?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'd like to execute a database query with date range. Problem: the `date` in the DB is a string, otherwise I'd write:

`from TimeTable where date between '2012-06-13' and '2012-06-15'`

How can I perform such operations when on `String date` type?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Check out the `to_date()` function

Comment: @membersound well i know mysql and you can use same way.I have created  sqlfiddle for you check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85159/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `to_timestamp`  
The `to_timestamp` function can also take a single double precision argument to convert from Unix epoch to timestamp with time zone. (Integer Unix epochs are implicitly cast to double precision.)
For example: `to_timestamp('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY');` 
 Read 
[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html)